# Spark Date Validation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

On my row data, one column has multiple date formats. I am trying to check the date format as per the below code. Most of all solutions on the web have the same answer but it's not working for me. The spark version is 3.0.

I tried to coalesce as well to check the NOT null value but it gave me the same error message.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df=spark.createDataFrame([["2023-03-11"],["15-03-2023"]],["inputDates"])
df1= df.select(when(to_date(col('inputDates'), "yyyy-MM-dd").isNotNull(), to_date(col('inputDates'), "yyyy-MM-dd")).otherwise(None))
display(df1)
```

Error message: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "15-03-2023"

Comment: Welcome to SO, please always post the full error stacktrace and state (with an example) the output you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try multiple date formats and then select the not null one

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

def parse_date(col, formats=("yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy")):
    return coalesce(*[to_date(col, f) for f in formats])

df=spark.createDataFrame([["2023-03-11"],["15-03-2023"]],["inputDates"])
df1= df.withColumn("parsed_date", parse_date(col('inputDates')))
display(df1)
```